# Issue authenticating Web api from MVC app

Tags: c#, owin, claims-based-identity, adfs3.0

I have MVC application and a Web Api hosted on different server. But i am not able to authenticate my web api's using ADFS if accessed from my mvc web app.

Getting "CORS Error"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Nuget Package Microsoft.ASP.Net.Cors and add [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")] attribute to your controller class

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public class YourController : ApiController
{ 
}
```

Add this in WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
  {
    config.EnableCors();
  }
```

You may check this [Link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).

Answer (score 0):

Please do not add a CORS filter with "*" (wild cards to allow any IP/Domain..).

Owasp's Cheat Sheet has some handy pointers and further information: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Cross_Origin_Resource_Sharing